# getting the third highest salary in MYSQL (your SQL syntax)

Tags: mysql

I want to find the third highest salary in tables in MySQl

```
select *
from 
(
    select ename, sal, dense_rank() over(order by sal desc) rank
    from emp
)
 where rank =3;
```

but I get this error message

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by salary desc)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase: I get this error message You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by salary desc) dense_rank from emp; ) as t where dense_rank=' at line 3

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that error message?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL every derived table requires an alias so it can be uniquely identified, so

```
select *
from 
(
    select ename, sal, dense_rank() over(order by sal desc) `rank`
    from emp
) as t
where `rank` = 3;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by salary desc) dense_rank from emp; ) as t where dense_rank=' at line 3

Comment: @nnmmss `rank` is a reserved word, you also need to `delimit` it. See edit.